# Some mysql development headers are missing after installing mysql-devel via yum

Tags: mysql, centos7, yum

I have tried to install Mysql-8.0.17 using official [guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/).
After it, MySQL works correctly but I found that some headers are missing:

```
$ cd /usr/include/mysql/mysql
$ ls
client_plugin.h  plugin_auth_common.h  udf_registration_types.h
```

For example, **plugin_auth.h** is missing. But I could find it in the source code [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/plugin__auth_8h.html).
And I am sure that I have installed all the necessary packages:

```
$ yum list installed | grep mysql
mysql-community-client.x86_64           8.0.17-1.el7                   @mysql80-community
mysql-community-common.x86_64           8.0.17-1.el7                   @mysql80-community
mysql-community-devel.x86_64            8.0.17-1.el7                   @mysql80-community
mysql-community-libs.x86_64             8.0.17-1.el7                   @mysql80-community
mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64      8.0.17-1.el7                   @mysql80-community
mysql-community-server.x86_64           8.0.17-1.el7                   @mysql80-community
mysql80-community-release.noarch        el7-3                          installed
```

The CentOS version is:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
```

Comment: My 5.7 has the `plugin_auth.h` but by 8.0.16 does not. Are you sure you are expecting to find that with the new version 8 mysql stuff? I know a lot of stuff got changed with regard to auth in the latest version.

Comment: I found it in the source code [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/plugin__auth_8h.html).
Updated the issue description with this info.

Comment: Yes, this works for MySQL 5.7. But for some reason, these headers are missing in 8.0 and persist in source code documentation.

Comment: No idea - sorry. Have you seen [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/writing-authentication-plugins.htm) kinda implies they should be included. Hopefully someone else can help.